# Python - Extract data from a specific table in a page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

just started to learn python. Spent the whole weekend for this project but the progress is terrible. Hopefully can get some guidance from the community.

Part of my tutorial required me to extract data from a google finance page. https://www.google.com/finance. But only the sector summary table. And then organize them into a JSON dump.

The questions I have so far is:

1) How to extract data from sector summary table only? I can find_all using  but the result come back include other table as well.

2) How do I get the change for each sectors ie: (energy : 0.99% , basic material : 0.31%, industrials : 0.17%). There are no unique tag I can used. The only characters is these numbers are below the same  as the sector name

Comment: Give us a proper URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the page (either using View Source or your browser's developer tools), we know a few things:

- The sector summary table is the only one inside a `div` tag with `id=secperf` (probably short for 'sector performance').
- For every row except the first, the first cell from the left contains the sector name; the second one from the left contains the change percentage.
- The other cells might contain bar graphs. The bar graphs also happen to be tables, but we want to ignore them, so we shouldn't recurse into them.

There are many ways to approach this. One way would be as follows:

```
def sector_summary(document):
    table = document.find(id='secperf').find('table')
    rows = table.find_all('tr', recursive=False)

    for row in rows[1:]:
        cells = row.find_all('td')

        sector = cells[0].get_text().strip()
        change = cells[1].get_text().strip()

        yield (sector, change)

print(dict(sector_summary(my_document)))
```